# Thingsboard Dashboard for All Customers

Tags: thingsboard

I have multiple customers with users for each of the customer groups. I have created a single dashboard which will be managed by myself (Tenant Admin). So if customer "A" logs in, I want them to see only their devices, on "my" dashboard. I had this setup working before but after making some updates to our repo, I am now not able to get customer users to see "my" dashboard. I'm not sure what I'm missing???

I have set the customer group dashboard to the one I want them to see their devices on. But when I login as the customer to test the update, the dashboard doesn't show up. I have also tried to manually set the home dashboard for the customer user but It still doesn't find "my" dashboard.[All Customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkF2.jpg)[Set Customer Home Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYnie.jpg)[Manually set Home Dashboard, not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jx2y.jpg)

Comment: Which ThingsBoard version do you have? Is it CE or PE?

Comment: @mdeuchert I am using the Cloud version

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, since both CE and PE are available in the cloud

Comment: @mdeuchert Apologies, I overlooked that. I believe we are using CE

Comment: https://demo.thingsboard.io/login --> CE

Comment: https://cloud.thingsboard.io/login --> PE

Comment: Only PE version has Role-based Access Control (RBAC): https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/rbac/

Comment: Sorry for all the back and forth, @mdeuchert, but I was able to confirm that we do have the PE cloud version.

Comment: No Problem, please include the ThingsBoard version (PE or CE) in future questions, since it can make a huge difference which version is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is only available for ThingsBoard PE instances & Part of the RBAC Feature (Role-Based Access Control):
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/rbac/

1. Create a Dashboard as template you would like to share to other customers
2. Define dynamic entity aliases which would work with different customers (e.g. all devices with type "thermometer" --> avoid single Device IDs)
3. Place the Dashboard in a Dashboard Group
4. Share the Group with the Customer of your choice (read, write or custom access)

[image]